# Iperf3 - Put hour/minutes/seconds at the beginning of each line

Tags: powershell, iperf, iperf3

I'm currently trying to launch a very long Iperf test on my infrastructure, so I'm developing some powershell script in order to do the tests.

To analyses the results, I want to have the hour/minutes/seconds of each new packet sends per lines on my output.

Currently, I'm using the -T argument like that on my script :

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\iperf3.exe" -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "-c",CLIENT_IP,"-t","86400","-p",5102,"-T","$(Get-Date -Format 'HH:mm:ss')","--logfile","C:\toto.txt"
```

But the output of the command just give me the current time when I launch the command like this:

```
03:40:56:  Connecting to host x.x.x.x, port 5201
03:40:56:  [  4] local x.x.x.x port 41674 connected to x.x.x.x port 5201
03:40:56:  [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr  Cwnd
03:40:56:  [  4]   0.00-1.00   sec   113 MBytes   946 Mbits/sec    0    208 KBytes       
03:40:56:  [  4]   1.00-2.00   sec   112 MBytes   943 Mbits/sec    0    208 KBytes       
03:40:56:  [  4]   2.00-3.00   sec   112 MBytes   939 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
03:40:56:  [  4]   3.00-4.00   sec   112 MBytes   942 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes       
03:40:56:  [  4]   4.00-5.00   sec   112 MBytes   940 Mbits/sec    0    210 KBytes
```

And I cannot find a way to increment the value with the current time without relaunching several times the command iperf3.exe.

Is there any solution to increment the value?
I can't do it with a "for"/"while" loop (in my opinion) because it's running a lot of iperf3 instance and it's not what is expected.

For information, I use the last version of iperf3-3.1.3 on Windows.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you want to record a timestamp every time it outputs a new line, you'll have to invoke it differently: `& C:\iperf3.exe args go here |ForEach-Object { "$(Get-Date -Format 'HH:mm:ss'): ${_}"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by [`iperf3`'s documentation](https://www.mankier.com/1/iperf3):

- **`-T` (`--title`) is for defining a *static* prefix** to prepend to each output line, due to passing [expandable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) string `"$(Get-Date -Format 'HH:mm:ss')"` as an argument, a *static* string representing the time *at the time of string expansion (interpolation)* is used.
- By contrast, **what you're looking for is the `--timestamps` option**, which causes a (true, event-related) timestamp to be prepended to each output line.

  - You can control the specific *format* of these timestamps via an optional argument, using a format string as used in the *Unix* `strftime()` library function.
  - These format strings are *not* compatible with .NET's date/time format strings (as used by [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date), for instance), so `HH:mm:ss` does *not* work; the `strftime()` equivalent is: `%H:%M:%S`

To put it all together:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\iperf3.exe' -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList @"
 -c $client_IP -t 86400 -p 5102 --logfile C:\toto.txt --timestamps=%H:%M:%S
"@
```

<sup>Note: I've substituted `CLIENT_IP` (which I assume was just a pseudo-code placeholder), with variable `$client_IP` - adjust as needed.</sup>

Comment: Hello @mklement0.
Thanks for your response, it was the point ! 
Let me just had some clarification to help other people:

I was trying to do this on Windows so i've download the last packet on https://iperf.fr.
But the version here is not maintain anymore by the author so you need to go on the github page and get the package from here: https://github.com/esnet/iperf
Also, if you want to have the new version of Iperf for windows, you need to download it from this page because the GitHub page provide a version only for linux: https://github.com/esnet/iperf/discussions/1258

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Pieo. Thanks for sharing the info on where to find the Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `--interval` or `--verbose` (for details) options?

Comment: I tried a form similar to Mathias' but with a loop of n times. You can try it that way or the following and it works.

`For ($i=0; $i -le 10; $i++) {
 iperf3 -c 127.0.0.1 -p 5201 -t 1 --verbose
 Write-Host "Time: $(Get-Date -Format 'HH:mm:ss') ${_}" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
}`

Keep in mind that the time printed would correspond to the time of the past execution.

Comment: Hello @Alex, I've tried with this solution, but as you say it print only the time of the past execution.
The response of mklement0 after is what I was searching for.

Thanks for your help.